# DELETE rows that are not in INSERT statement mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, delete-row

I have following situation:

I have a mysql table in which I upload my inventory. The table's structure is like:

```
<pre>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>SKU</th>
                <th>price</th>
                <th>quantity</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>393939</td>
                <td>39.99</td>
                <td>32</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</pre>
```

Actually I do it as follows:

```
mysqli_query(
    $sql, 
    "INSERT IGNORE INTO de_minmaxpreis(sku, price, quantity) VALUES ('$teile[3]', '$teile[4]', '$teile[5]')"
);
```

Now, if I have data taken out of the inventoryfile I use to import, I want that the data which isn't in the inventoryfile be deleted from the table. I can't truncate the table prior to import the new file, because pricing details might have changed and the priority to this is in my mySql table. (More up to date).

Hm, hope someone understands my question and can help.

Comment: Do you have some sort of id on both tables so you can `DELETE FROM t WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT id FROM import table)`?

Comment: @Mihai No I don't, I don't import from a table, but from a file. But I have an SKU Number which is unique in the table I import to and in the importfile, can I use this statement with an insert statement from a file in any way? ( DELETE FROM t WHERE SKU NOT IN $array)

Comment: This looks terrifyingly insecure. Are you **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php)? `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Comment: I would do it like this:import your data into an intermediary table JOIN this table with your table ON sku and delete anything which is outside this JOIN.

Comment: @tadman You're right, I'm just about to rewrite the whole application to PDO. In this certain case I'm sure to have properly escaped parameters. thank you, I will try it like this! Seems like I can try it with PDO by the way...

Comment: You're talking about inventory but ignore quantity?

Comment: @michael The key is to use placeholder values rather than string interpolation. You can do this with [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) when using `mysqli`.

Comment: @tadman Working on it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you right , you need to insert just new SKUs and delete ones that are not present in new import. Meaning you do not need to update anything from new import like "quantity" 
If so you can do, and assuming that **sku** is unique.

```
$sql="select sku from de_minmaxpreis";
//get the skus in array like $oldskus[]='somesku';

//make a new data array look like $newDataSkus[$sku]=$dataArray;
foreach($oldskus as $oldSku){
  //here if odlsku is not present in new data delete it from a DB
  if( ! array_key_exists($oldSku , $newDataSkus ){
     //old sku not present anymore delete it
     $sql="delete from de_minmaxpreis .... "
  }else{
    //as sku is in DB remove that sku from newData at the end you will get data that is new and needs to be inserted
      unset($newDataSkus[$oldSku];
  } 

}
//finally inset new data
foreach($newDataSkus as $tiele){
mysqli_query(
    $dbCon, 
    "INSERT INTO de_minmaxpreis(sku, price, quantity) VALUES ('$teile[3]', '$teile[4]', '$teile[5]')"
);
}
```